# How to use Aggregate in AppSmith

Tags: appsmith

In my database of MongoDB, I can't insert new register in the historial
I want insert the phone and start date
My model in Mongo is this

[image: 1]

And the code what write is this

```
{
    "aggregate": "dids",
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "$match": {
                "_id": ObjectId({{sPhone.selectedOptionValue}})
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor": {
        "batchSize": 10
    }
}
```

how insert $addFields in pipeline segment?

```
"$addFields": {
                "history.contract_id": {{tableOfContracts.selectedRow._id}},
                "history.start_date": {{dtpkStart.selectedDate}}
            }
```

Yes is written below the match segment,  throws error ('A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field')

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To insert data, you can consult it in the appsmith documentation in the following links.

Link to the explanation of mongodb methods: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/insert-methods/

Link to query syntax: https://docs.appsmith.com/reference/datasources/querying-mongodb/mongo-syntax

Query configuration:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z5Yy.png)